# Sync contacts under an account

Tags: trigger

I would like an edit  single contact record on an account to mass-update all other contact records on the same account with the same change
I have above requirement and I have created the trigger for it

```
trigger syncContact on Contact (after update) {
    map<id,string> conMap = new map<id,string>();
    set<id> accId = new set<Id>();
    for(Contact c : Trigger.new)
    {
        conMap.put(c.Id,c.Title);
        accId.add(c.AccountId);
    }
    List<contact> conList = new List<contact>();
    if(recursiveCheck.runOnce() && trigger.isupdate)
    {
        for(account a : [select id,(select id,title from contacts where id not in : conMap.keySet() ) from account where id in : accId])
        {
            conList.add(a.contacts);
            for(contact c : a.contacts)
            {
             c.Title=conMap.get(id);   
                conlist.add(c);
            }
        }
    }
update conlist;
}
```

I am not getting to how to put the id of contact updated in the mapcon.get()

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put this field at the Account level and then use a cross-object formula field on Contact to pull the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trigger syncContact on Contact (after update) {
    map<id,string> conMap = new map<id,string>();
    set<id> accId = new set<Id>();
    for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
        conMap.put(c.AccountId,c.Title);
        accId.add(c.id);
    }
    List<contact> conList = new List<contact>();
    if(recursiveCheck.runOnce() && trigger.isupdate){
        for(account a : [select id,(select id,AccountId,title from contacts where id not in : accId ) from account where id in : conMap.keySet()]){
            for(contact c : a.contacts){
                c.Title=conMap.get(c.AccountId);   
                conlist.add(c);
            }
        }
    }
    update conlist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the trouble you're having is that you can't identify which contact is the master contact, the one whose change you want to duplicate on all the contacts with the same account.

I think you can fix your problem by using the the related account ID as the key for conMap and the contact title as the value, that way you don't need to know which contact is the correct contact, you only need to know their shared parent account!

Your finished code would look like this:

```
trigger syncContact on Contact (after update) {
    map<Id, String> conMap = new map<Id, String>();
    for(Contact c : Trigger.new) { 
        conMap.put(c.AccountID,c.Title);
    } 

    List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>(); 
    if(recursiveCheck.runOnce() && trigger.isupdate) { 
        for(account a : 
                [select id,
                (select id,title from contacts where id not in : Trigger.newMap.keyset() ) 
                from account where id in : conMap.keyset()]) { 
            conList.add(a.contacts); 
            for(contact c : a.contacts) { 
                c.Title=conMap.get(a.id);
                conlist.add(c); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    update conlist; 
}
```

I was able to get this to compile in a dev sandbox, with the exception of the recursiveCheck, so it should hopefully do the trick for you. If this had've been in a handler class instead of the trigger itself I might have been able to write a quick test as well, perhaps try that in the future.

Comment: I am getting below error :

Error:Apex trigger syncContact caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: syncContact: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.ListException: Duplicate id in list: 0036F00002JM1NsQAL: Trigger.syncContact: line 20, column 1

using the above trigger

Comment: If you're getting duplicates that probably means you have multiple contacts with the same parent account getting updated at the same time. There might be a more elegant solution, but if you change conList to a Set<Contacts> instead of a list then you shouldn't get that trouble, as sets are automatically de-duplicated and can't contain empty records.

Comment: no its not working